# How do I use ember-data to model this setup in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, ember.js, mongomapper, ember-data

I have an Item that can have many Sections. I store it in mongodb as an Item document with many Section embedded documents.

The Item can have a lot of Sections.

What is the recommended way to do this in ember-data?

When a Section is changed, should I be sending the whole Item to the server, and there working out which Section has changed and updating just that section via atomic set?

OR, should I be sending just the Section to the server to update?

I dont want to lock the whole document up when saving the whole thing, which I think will be slow.

Also, each Section can be re-ordered within the Item, so they contain their order position as an attribute. If I am just sending the changed Section's JSON to the server, I will potentially have to send a lot of changed section requests to the server.

Comment: Are you sure embedded documents are the best choice? With a non-embedded association, this problem nearly goes away.